# How to create such a top element

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to generate an xml document with attributes that needs to look as

```
<Prenos
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Verzija="2.1"
>
```

The closest I got was with this code

```
$root_element = $xml->createElementNS( 'http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd', 'Prenos' );
$root_element = $xml->appendChild( $root_element );
$root_element->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$root_element->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation', 'http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd');
$root_element->setAttribute( 'Verzija', '2.1' );
```

But it creates me such an element

```
<Prenos
    Verzija="2.1"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd"
>
```

Comment: It would nice, if you would describe what is wrong about the solution that you got (seems equivalent to me).

Comment: @Gerriet my generated xml doesn't get validated by schema and this is the only difference I have with the example xml. All other elements are the correct type, size and times they occure. Even the programer of the program that imports those xml files didn't see any mistakes in the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You create the node `Prenos` in the namespace `http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd`. But the output expects it in the 'none' namespace.

```
$root_element = $xml->createElement( 'Prenos' );
$root_element = $xml->appendChild( $root_element );
$root_element->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$root_element->setAttributeNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation', 'http://www.somesite.si/xml/schema.xsd');
$root_element->setAttribute( 'Verzija', '2.1' );
```